# Python: Check if any of the words in a list are present in a document

Tags: python, list, keyword

I am trying to 'teach' myself Python. Currently I am using the free Python course available on Udacity. I am also reading HTLPTHW.

One of the modules is a bit dated, and asks that you use the URLLIB module for a website that is now defunct. What it did was state True / False, based on if a curse word was present in a given document. It referenced the file, input its contents after reading into the URL search, which then resolved as either being True / False after the search.

I was thinking of ways to get around this, and I thought I could use a list of swears that would be searched for in the document. If a swear in the list was also found in the open document, it would give an alert.

I'm running into some issues, and part might be that I kept most of the original format of the code based on the tutorial--meaning a lot of it may be tailored to the URLLIB method, rather than a keyword search.

```
def read_text():
    quotes = open("/Users/Ishbar/Desktop/movie_quotes.txt")
    contents_of_file = quotes.read()
    print(contents_of_file)
    quotes.close()
    check_profanity(contents_of_file)

def check_profanity(text_to_check):
    Word_db = ["F***","S***","A**"]
    quotes = open("/Users/Ishbar/Desktop/movie_quotes.txt")
    contents_of_file = quotes.read()
    output == Word_db
    if str(Word_db) in quotes.read():
        output == 1
    if output == 1:
        print("Profanity Alert!!")
    elif output == 0:
        print("This document has no curse words.")
    else:
        print("ERROR: Could not scan the document properly.")
read_text()
```

I just can't get the code happy. I either always get profanity found, or no profanity found. I thought I could have it modify what output is, and output's default state to be no profanity unless otherwise found.

To that end, do I even need to has an elif for profanity / absence, if it is always absent, otherwise present?

Answer (score 2):

Since you already read the contents of the file in `read_text()` you don't have to read the file again in `check_profanity()`

Also, the line `if str(Word_db) in quotes.read():` converts the list to a string and checks if it is present in the file. It is equivalent to:

`if '["F***","S***","A**"]' in quotes.read()`

You need check if **any** element of the list is present in the file. This can be done using a `for` loop.

```
def check_profanity(text_to_check):
    Word_db = ["bad","verybad"]
    if set(Word_db).intersection(set(text_to_check.split())):
        print("Profanity Alert!!")
    else:
        print("This document has no curse words.")

check_profanity("this file contains bad words") # 1st call
check_profanity("this file contains good words") #2nd call
```

**Output:**

> Profanity Alert!!
>
> This document has no curse words.

You can do this using regular expressions too.

```
import re
if re.search("("+")|(".join(Word_db)+")", quotes.read()):
   print("Profanity Alert!!")
else:
   print("This document has no curse words.")
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just encountered a similar problem(also doing the udacity course). Doubtless you will have moved on from this yourself some time ago, but this was my solution in the end. Following from gaganso, and using a .csv list of profanities(https://www.frontgatemedia.com/a-list-of-723-bad-words-to-blacklist-and-how-to-use-facebooks-moderation-tool/):

```
    def read_text():
    text = open("twoSentences.txt")
    contents = text.read()
    #print(contents)
    return(str(contents))
    text.close()

    a_text = read_text()

    def check_curse(sample_text):
    curse_list = open("Terms-to-Block.csv")
    curse_words = str(curse_list.read())  
    sep_text = sample_text.split()
    sep_curses = curse_words.split()
    if set(sep_curses).intersection(set(sep_text)):
        print("ALERT")
    else:
        print("OK")

    check_curse(a_text)
```

Comment: NB also using python 3.6.5 as apposed to python 2 - another slight issue with the udacity course!

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to do it explicitly :

```
def check_profanity(document_to_check):
    Word_db = ["F***","S***","A**"]
    with open(document_to_check) as quotes:     # let's open the document
        for line in quotes:                     # parse it line by line
            for word in Word_db:                # check offensing words one by one
                if word in line:
                    return True                 # if found one bad word, go out :-)

if check_profanity("/Users/Ishbar/Desktop/movie_quotes.txt"):
    print "Profanity Alert!!"
else:
    print("This document has no curse words.")
```

Of course, an experienced python developer could rewrite it in less lines, but before doing it magically, you'll have to learn how to do it explicitly :)